# How to find the plane in this problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine an equation for the plane that consists of all points with equal distance to the point A = (1,2,3) as to the point B = (3, −2, −1).

I have one lead at that is that the center of the distance between A and B is in the plane.

How can i figure out the plane in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the midpoint of $AB$ is on the plane and that's also orthogonal to the segment/vector $AB$.

Midpoint of $AB$ is the arithmetic mean of $A$ and $B$, coordinatewise, so it's $P=(2,0,1)$ and the vector ${\bf n}=\overrightarrow{AB}$ is the difference $B-A$ coordinatewise: ${\bf n}=(2,-4,-4)$.

We might take any parallel vector to ${\bf n}$, say $(-1,2,2)$. These make up the coefficients in the equation of the plane:
$$-x+2y+2z=c$$
and to find the value of $c$, simply plug in the coordinates of $P$, that should satisfy the equation.

Comment: Thanks how do i get the variable D?

Comment: There's no $D$ at all.